# Identify Facebook app is in canvas or not

Tags: php, facebook

How can i identify that, either my Facebook app is running inside Facebook canvas or outside canvas (as we access website like www.example.com).

i tried to get URL staying inside Facebook canvas like,

```
echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

but it return the same URL like outside of the canvas,
i visited [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/) link, but i didn't find any useful material..

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to see if `$_POST['signed_request']` is set. When your app URL is requested inside the canvas or inside a page-tab then Facebook sends the signed request POST parameter to the server. When it is not set, you can be confident the application is running outside of Facebook.

You can decode `$_POST['signed_request']` with the following code, if you need to get some of the [data it contains](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/):

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  $secret = "appsecret"; // Use your app secret here

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  // confirm the signature
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

If you don't need the data, just check that it is set.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['signed_request'])) works like charm, you are master man!

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver + PHP script has no idea it's loaded from inside an iframe. So you need to find a way to make that happen. You could add a parameter to the URL query string when supplying your canvas app url to facebook. Like:

```
www.example.com/?from=facebook
```

Then in your PHP script you can check if the request was coming from FB by accessing:

> $_GET['from'];